# Effect of GBW and slew rate for "small signal"

Tags: operational-amplifier, bandwidth, small-signal, slew-rate, gain-bandwidth-product

I would like to better understand how to choose an op amp for high speed application and more precisely I would like to better understand how the GBW and the slew rate influence the transient response/setling time for "small signal". By small signal I would say for exemple a pulse with a rise time of about 100 ns and an amplitude between 100mV and 1V. (Gain of op amp is equal to 5 and it is set as a difference op amp)

I think that if the amplitude of the pulse is low, the slew rate will have negligeable effect on the response time of the system.

The following [document](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidueh2c/tidueh2c.pdf?ts=1676632230645&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) from TI gives some results but the results are for "large signals" :

[image]

It would be nice if the same thing could exist for small signals.

Thank you,

Comment: It is possible to assess the effects of the GBW and slew-rate of the op-amp used in a compensator. I covered these in my [APEC 2015](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202015.pdf) seminar. I would say that it matters when you start pushing crossover beyond 10 kHz or so, like in 50- or 100-kHz crossover designs for instance. Please also note that slew-rate issues are nonlinear large-signal effects that can be modeled in small-signal but using an appropriate (complicated) mathematical tool.

Comment: @VerbalKint Thank you for this comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to decide for yourself what is the maximum output amplitude peak and then proceed.

The slew rate is a *large-signal* parameter of the op-amp, while the GBWP is an *small-signal* one.

The slew rate expression is derived from:
$$
\frac{d[V_p\sin(2\pi ft)]}{dt} = 2\pi f V_p \cos(\omega t) 
$$

Therefore, if you know your max. voltage peak \$V_p\$, as I mentioned initially, you can then find out what is the maximum frequency you can operate at (i.e. *your large-signal bandwidth*) without suffering from slew-rate distortion:
$$
  f_{max} = \frac{SR}{2\pi V_p}
$$

As you correctly recognize, slew rate won't be that much of a problem if your peak amplitude is low (within limits).

The SR spec is given in a datasheet, but usually under fixed conditions that may not match yours. I'd suggest you simulate it and prove to yourself whether your "small" signal is small enough that SR isn't a problem.

Also, if you have a gain of 5 your output amplitude could be 5V. If so, that doesn't sound like an small signal (unless your supply is in the tens of volts).

Answer (score 1):

> *By small signal I would say for example a pulse with a rise time of
> about 100 ns and an amplitude between 100mV and 1V. (Gain of op amp is
> equal to 5 and it is set as a difference op amp)*

Your output could be as high as 5 volts (gain of 5 with an input amplitude of 1 volt) so, to avoid op-amp slew rate becoming a problem, you need it to have a slew rate that exceeds 50 volts / μs.

> *I think that if the amplitude of the pulse is low, the slew rate will
> have negligible effect on the response time of the system.*

That is normally the case. Regarding GBWP...

If your input signal is (say) a 1 MHz square wave then, you have to think about what level of pulse distortion you can accept before you can pick an op-amp with sufficient GBWP. You also need to take into account that you have a gain of 5. Personally, I'd do this bit in a simulator using an ideal op-amp purposefully rigged to have a defined and alterable GBWP. It's not hard to do once you master how to use a simulator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: Actually I do not know that It was possible to simulate all these parameters easily !

Comment: GBWP is easy to simulate. Slew rate is a simple go/no-go calculation based on peak amplitude.